# What is the right location for scriptlet?

Tags: class, jsp, arraylist, scriptlet

I have declared a separate class named Questions, and another JSP file named SetQuestions.jsp.

```
public SurveyQuestionBean()
{

}

public SurveyQuestionBean(String question_description, String file_type, String file_url, String question_type, String answer_type, int min_choice, int max_choice, boolean add_others)
{
       this.question_description = question_description;
       this.file_type = file_type;
       this.file_url = file_url;
       this.question_type = question_type;
       this.answer_type = answer_type;
       this.min_choice = min_choice;
       this.max_choice = max_choice;
       this.add_others = add_others;
}
```

the code above is taken for the class, and i have the get method for each of the attributes. For the JSP, i have the properties for user to input. And after clicking add button, i will want to add the inputs into a ArrayList first as there might be more than 1 question. Only when the user clicks finish button, it will then go into the database.

```
    <%

    ArrayList<Questions> ListOfQuestion = new ArrayList<Questions>();
%>
```

i have declared the Arraylist, however how do i add the Questions object to the list everytime the user clicks add button? i am stucked for hours, novice here by the way.

Comment: check 'request.getParameter(btname!=null)' for the action of button click and within that write your corresponding logic. Also in your form action, write the name of the same JSP page

Comment: thank you gau123 for your quick reply, will try it out!

Comment: If possible then avoid `scriplet's coding` because if `page crash your code will be shown` so make `List of String or etc.` and pass it to JSP and on JSP recieve that List and further display and process it so only list came on JSP so no other code will be exposed.